Playwright dialog - how to display it?
Playwright auto-dismisses dialogs. Is there any way how to NOT dismiss it and actually display it?
To be clear -> When I open some website via chromium (var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions { Headless = false }); ...) and inject the js alert ("This is a warning message!"); nothing happens. Is there any way how to override playwright settings and display dialog?
Thanks

Please share a [mcve] -- a page under test and complete, runnable code illustrating your attempt. How are you injecting the alert, exactly and why do you want to do this? Thanks.

To handle dialogues in Playwright, we need to listen for the dialogue event and then interact with dialogue and prevent them for auto-dismissing.
Attach an event listener to the page that listens for dialog events.


const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Launch the browser
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  // Attach an event listener to handle dialogs
  page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    console.log(`Dialog message: ${dialog.message()}`);
    await dialog.accept(); // or dialog.dismiss();
  });

  // Navigate to your desired page
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  // Inject an alert dialog using JavaScript
  await page.evaluate(() => alert('This is a warning message!'));

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

  await browser.close();
})();



